# Is it possible to control the whitespace of exported pdf in ggplot

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

When I export my plots with ggplot I get a lot of whitespace, especially when I use `top` arrangement for a legend.

When writing scientific paper the page limits are very strict and wasting one, two, three lines on the whitespace of a plot is really costly.

Is it possible to tweak the whitespace around plots saved with `ggsave()`?

I came to know that this whitespace is also known as "bleed" in design terminology, if that helps anyone...

[image]

The same is also visible [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/figure/unnamed-chunk-16-1.png):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`theme()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) with parameters to your plot. Some parameters that might be useful are `plot.margin` and `legend.margin`.